# Deployment using jenkins in salesforce org

Tags: deployment, jenkins-pipeline, salesforce, salesforce-sfdx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dCws.png)I am doing integrating my salesforce org with the Jenkins. I'm using build configuration using Jenkins file so im getting this error again and again [Please find the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmQ4y.png)

i want to generate the SSL certificate for this and validate the salesforce org with the jenkins